# How to upgrade from Groovy to Hydro?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, ros-groovy, update

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have ROS Groovy installed. Is their any way to upgrade to Hydro using terminal commands?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131846/how-to-upgrade-from-groovy-to-hydro?/) by [expelliarmus](https://answers.ros.org/users/5244/expelliarmus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2014-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should just install Hydro as described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Installation). This will install Hydro in addition to your existing Groovy installation. If you really want to, you can uninstall Groovy via "sudo apt-get remove ros-groovy-*" but you really [don't need to](http://answers.ros.org/question/10660/what-happened-if-i-install-two-version-of-ros/?answer=15729#post-id-15729). I have both versions on my computer and I switch back and forth when I need to by changing my .bashrc file from "source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash" to "source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash" along with the catkin and package paths, then restarting the terminal.

---

Originally posted by [Angus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2171/angus/) with karma: 438 on 2014-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [expelliarmus](https://answers.ros.org/users/5244/expelliarmus/) on 2014-02-24**:
Sounds good to me, as I have to work in both versions.
Does this mean that I have to maintain separate catkin_ws or can I have different Groovy and Hydro packages in the same Catkin_ws?

**Comment by [Angus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2171/angus/) on 2014-02-24**:
I believe the default recommendation is to use separate workspaces. I'm not sure if you could use same workspace but I don't see any reason why not.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-02-24**:
You should NOT use the same workspace since CMake will use CMake config files from the location available in the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH when it is configured the first time. When you then switch the ROS distro those locations will not be updated. Therefore you would end up with a mixed up workspace.